# Multiple uvmaps for single object for texturing blender 2.9

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, faces

I am trying to texture my object (a single object) with multiple different textures.

Suppose my object has 3 different textures, i plan to map faces which have a particular type of texture to a single uvmap (so eventually i should have 3 uvmaps with different sets of vertices and faces on different uvmaps).

I know how to assign multiple uvmaps to an object. however the issue is when i switch between maps, the faces i selected for the previous uvmap are lost. and if i hit the uv sync key (in uv editor mode), all the faces of my object show up in uvmap!

I wanted to know how to ensure the faces i selected and unwrapped for a particular uvmap remain on that uvmap and are not lost (even if i switch maps)? exporting the uvmap (as png etc.) is not an option as i may need to reorient the faces later for texturing.

Perhaps my workflow is the issue - if i want to assign different textures to different faces - is it better to split the mesh into seperate smaller objects and then assign textures to them?
or is there some other better work flow for this? the issue with splitting the object into smaller objects is that if i later decide to apply subsurf mod to my objects (for higher poly count), the smaller object will deform seperately and so the objects wont line up!!!

Is it possible to render the different uvmaps for different faces (of the same object) all at the same time? in blender 2.9, in the uvmaps tab, i only able to enable one uvmap at a time for rendering!

What is the better approach/workflow here?

Comment: The better workflow is to use a single object, a single UV map, and multiple *materials*, where each material references a different texture image.  I think you're misunderstanding how UV and materials and textures work.  All faces are UV mapped in all UV maps; changing UV maps doesn't lose any mapping in other UV maps; but you need to specify (probably in nodes) which UV map you want to use to reference each texture image, individually.

Comment: "where each material references a different texture image"